# Dagger-2: How to wire up my program, if I have to inject dependencies at runtime?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I think this is a very fundamental question, where I couldn't find a answer for. My setup is as following:

My main component (used to make dependencies available to the entire object graph, e.g. Jackson's ObjectMapper.class, that is provided by the ModuleUtils.class)

```
@Component(modules = {
    ModuleApplication.class,
    ModuleUtils.class
})
public interface ComponentApplication {
   ComponentSocketManager.Builder componenetSocketManagerBuilder();
}
```

My subcomponent (used to create the SocketManager)

```
@Subcomponent(modules = ModuleSocketManager.class)
public interface ComponentSocketManager {

   //Subcomponent is used to create a SocketManager
   SocketManager socketManager();

   @Subcomponent.Builder
   interface Builder {

    //SocketManager requires a Socket to work with, which is only 
    //available at runtime
    @BindsInstanceBuilder socket(Socket socket);
    ComponentSocketManager build();
    }
}
```

At runtime of the program, sockets are spawned and new SocketManagers can be instantiated with the help of Dagger2:

```
Socket socket = this.serverSocket.accept();
//Here the wiring of the object graph is somehow interrupted, as I need
//to inject objects at runtime, that are required for the wiring process
SocketManager sm = DaggerComponentApplication.create()
                     .componenetSocketManagerBuilder()
                     .socket(socket) //inject the socket at runtime
                     .build()
                     .socketManager();

//I don't want to wire my app manually. Dagger should do the wiring of the
//entire object graph, not only up to the point where I inject at runtime
AppBusinessLogic appBusinessLogic = ... //some deeply nested wiring
MyApp app = new MyApp(sm, appBusinessLogic);
Thread thread = new Thread(app);   //new thread for every client
thread.start();
```

The problem is how I manually intervene into the "wiring process" of dagger2 and how AppBusinessLogic is created. AppBusinessLogic basically represents the entire program and is a deeply nested object graph.

What I want: 
Initialize the entire program at startup (without "breaking" the wiring process). Rather inject dependencies at runtime into the completed object graph that contains some sort of "placeholders" for the runtime dependencies.

Why do I want that?
I want to reuse dependencies from the parent components. E.g. in the example above ComponentApplication has an ObjectMapper-dependencies. How can I reuse exactly that instance for my "appBusinessLogic" object? Of course I could have sth like a ComponentAppBusinessLogic, that inherits from ComponentApplication. However using ComponentAppBusinessLogic to create a "appBusinessLogic"-object would result into a new ObjectMapper-dependency?

 So, how can I wire up the entire program at initialization phase and use dagger's inheritance concept? Or how do I avoid interrupting the wiring process of the entire program when I have dependencies at runtime to inject?

Answer (score 0):

When your parent component has a binding for `ObjectMapper` then your subcomponent has access to this. That means you could create provision methods in your subcomponent like...

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {SubcomponentModule.class})
public interface MySubcomponent {
    ...
    ObjectMapper objectMapper(); // e.g. singleton bound by parent component
    ...
}
```

and you can depend on such objects in the subcomponent modules

```
@Module
public class SubcomponentModule {
    @Provides
    Foo provideFoo(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new Foo(objectMapper);
    }
}
```

See also [Dagger Subcomponents](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html)

Comment: That's true, but i think my problem was a totally different one. I tried to instantiate different components all over the place and build my sub graphs from there (which is a bad idea, because how do i share/reuse the dependencies between the bean containers/component instances?). Obviously my intention should be, to instantiate/wire together the ENTIRE program st startup from one component, which allows me to have all dependencies in one container, right? (maybe use subcomponents there to exchange entire subgraphs of the program).

Comment: I am sorry when I misunderstood your problem. You wrote _"However using ComponentAppBusinessLogic to create a "appBusinessLogic"-object would result into a new ObjectMapper-dependency?"_. What I eventually understood from this sentence is that it describes an equivalent situation to the one above: Providing a `Foo` instance that depends on an `ObjectMapper` instance. Now when the latter is `@Singleton` scoped, each new `Foo` instance will be instantiated with the same `ObjectMapper` instance.